# How to use f:loadbundle with facelets

Tags: jsf, facelets, jsf-1.2

Using f:loadbundle when using jsp as the view description language for an JSF application is pretty straight forward.

**I want to know where to put this f:loadbundle when i am using facelets**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except from the way the taglibs are declared, it's really not different from JSP.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <f:loadBundle basename="com.example.i18n.text" var="text" />
    <head>
        <title>Facelets page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h:outputText value="#{text['some.key']}" />
    </body>  
</html>
```

This also applies to all other tags/components. The only major difference is that you need to declare the taglib in a XML namespace instead of an old fashioned JSP `<%@taglib %>` thingy.

Comment: Thanks for the response BalusC.Can i declare <f:loadBundle> outside the ui:composition tags?

Comment: No. Anything outside `<ui:composition>` is ignored. Just declare it inside.

Comment: So it also belongs outside `f:head`? See my `base.tpl` at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537018/doctype-not-rendered-in-jsf-master-template

Comment: Still for a `f:viewParam id="fooId" name="fooId" required="true" requiredMessage="#{bundle.PARAMETER_FOO_ID_IS_REQUIRED}"` my `p:message for="fooId"` remains with no message shown but tag is rendered (means I see an empty alert box).