# doctype not rendered in JSF "master" template

Tags: jsf, primefaces, mojarra, payara, jsf-2.3

As the subject said, the needed doctype is not rendered in my JSF pages. My used versions:

- Payara Server  Payara Server  4.1.2.181 #badassfish (build 220)]]
- Mojarra 2.3.3 ( 20171008-2230 673408fa9199477d87f44521ff873d709128c88b)
- PrimeFaces 6.2 ("official" version)

I already tried the bundled (2.2.14/13/15?) version, no change, so I upgraded to 2.3.3 from github (official release).

In my entire project I have only one doctype and that is in my "master" template:

`base.tpl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
                xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
                xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">

    <h:doctype rootElement="html" public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

    <html lang="#{localizationController.locale.language}" xml:lang="#{localizationController.locale.language}" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <f:view locale="#{localizationController.locale}" contentType="text/html" />
        <h:head>
            <f:facet name="first">
                <ui:insert name="metadata" />

                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
                <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
            </f:facet>

            <f:loadBundle var="msg" basename="org.mxchange.localization.generic" />
            <f:loadBundle var="project" basename="org.mxchange.localization.project" />
            <f:loadBundle var="local" basename="org.mxchange.localization.local" />

            <h:outputStylesheet name="/css/custom.css" />

            <title>
                <h:outputText value="#{initParam['project_title']} - " />

                <ui:insert name="document_title">
                    <h:outputText value="Default document title" />
                </ui:insert>
            </title>
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <pm:page id="master">
                <h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-fluid" layout="block">
                    <pm:header>
                        <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="page-header" layout="block">
                                <h1>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{initParam['project_title']} - " />

                                    <ui:insert name="content_header">
                                        <h:outputText value="Default header title" />
                                    </ui:insert>
                                </h1>
                            </h:panelGroup>

                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="page-content-gap" layout="block">
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </pm:header>

                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-g" layout="block">
                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-g-12 ui-md-2" layout="block">
                            <ui:insert name="menu">
                                <h:outputText value="Default menu" />
                            </ui:insert>

                            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/widgets/locale_change_widget.tpl" />
                        </h:panelGroup>

                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-g-12 ui-md-10 ui-g-nopad" layout="block">
                            <h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-g-12 ui-g-nopad">
                                <ui:insert name="content">
                                    <h:outputText value="Default content" />
                                </ui:insert>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </h:panelGroup>

                        <h:panelGroup styleClass="ui-g-12 page-footer" layout="block">
                            <ui:insert name="footer">
                                <h:outputText value="Default footer" />
                            </ui:insert>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <h:panelGroup styleClass="error-container" layout="block">
                        <p:growl showDetail="true" sticky="true">
                            <p:autoUpdate />
                        </p:growl>

                        <p:ajaxExceptionHandler
                            type="javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException"
                            update="exceptionDialog"
                            onexception="PF('exceptionDialog').show();"
                            />

                        <p:dialog id="exceptionDialog" closable="true" closeOnEscape="true" header="Exception '#{pfExceptionHandler.type}' occured!" widgetVar="exceptionDialog"
                                  height="500px">
                            <div class="para">
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg.EXCEPTION_MESSAGE}:" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{pfExceptionHandler.message}" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="para">
                                <h:outputText value="#{msg.EXCEPTION_STACK_TRACE}:" />
                                <h:outputText value="#{pfExceptionHandler.formattedStackTrace}" escape="false" />
                            </div>

                            <div class="para">
                                <p:button onclick="window.location.href = document.location.href;"
                                          value="#{msg.RELOAD_PAGE}"
                                          rendered="#{pfExceptionHandler.type == 'javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException'}" />
                            </div>
                        </p:dialog>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </pm:page>
        </h:body>
    </html>
</ui:composition>
```

Many JSF pages looks like this:

`some_guest_page.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/guest/guest_base.tpl"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
                xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
                xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
                xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

    <ui:define name="guest_title">
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.PAGE_TITLE_INDEX_FOO}" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content_header">
        <h:outputText value="#{msg.CONTENT_TITLE_INDEX_FOO}" />
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <!-- @TODO Here goes your content. //-->
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The mentioned `guest_base.tpl` is a layer beetween the actual page and my "master" template:

`guest_base.tpl`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ui:composition
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/base.tpl"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">

    <ui:define name="document_title">
        <ui:insert name="document_guest_title">
            <h:outputText value="Default guest title" />
        </ui:insert>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="menu">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{featureController.isFeatureEnabled('guest_menu')}">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/guest/guest_menu.tpl" />
        </ui:fragment>
    </ui:define>

    <ui:define name="footer">
        <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/templates/guest/guest_footer.tpl" />
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this is warmly welcome. :-)

**UPDATE:**
Fixed `base.tpl` slightly. Now at least the locale is being correctly loaded again. `f:view` seems to also cover at least `h:head`, `h:body` and `f:loadBundle` which makes sense:

- `f:view` component sets the locale
- `f:loadBundle` loads the with the set locale associated message bundle

But now, still the major problem, no `doctype`, is still present.

Comment: Is this right? https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/4004#issuecomment-298599500

Comment: updated `base.tpl`, still no doctype, I took this as an example: https://github.com/javaserverfaces/mojarra/issues/2457#issuecomment-298568700

Comment: It seems to be a known bug in Mojarra but should have worked with much older versions (see here on stackoverflow). Sure it makes sense defining your doctype in your "master" template that is included everywhere in your views to keep required work low.